# Functional Square Root of Derivative

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

The derivative can be seen as a linear operator $\frac{d}{dx} : C^1(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow C^0(\mathbb{R})$. *Does there exist another linear operator $ D : C^1(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow C^0(\mathbb{R}) $ such that the composition of $D$ with itself gives the derivative operator? (That is, $D \circ D = \frac{d}{dx}$)*

My inclination would be that such an operator would not exist, but I haven't been able to prove this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is called [Fractional Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus). You can even differentiate $\sqrt{2}$ times.

Comment: More specifically: the operation is sometimes called a *semiderivative*.